# Setting the field selection of a SELECT statement with the Stored Procedure's Input Variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

The following simple Stored Procedure fails to return a result set, even though running this simple SELECT statement in isolation with the actual value works just fine.  Any ideas why?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PageHeadingGetText]
    @PageType nvarchar(100)
AS

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT @PageType FROM [dbo].[PageHeadingText] 
END
```

Comment: `SELECT @PageType FROM [dbo].[PageHeadingText]` will return the value of `@PageType` as many times as there are rows in that table. Is that really the intended behaviour? If not what is it supposed to do?

Comment: I am *guessing* that you are trying to pass in a list of columns that you want to select. You **cannot** do this however, in T-SQL. You **cannot** parametrize the list of columns or the table name with variables. If you want to do this, you must use *dynamic SQL* (concatenating together your SQL statement inside the stored procedure, and then executing it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't ask directly but in the title you say "Setting the field selection of a SELECT".
You have to use dynamic SQL to dynamically build a statement :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PageHeadingGetText]
    @columns nvarchar(max)
AS

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @sqlCommand NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT ' + @columns + ' FROM [dbo].[PageHeadingText]' 

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand
END
```

Comment: Should probably mention SQL injection.

Comment: Which you just did :) But you are right it could be prone to sql injection, please have a look to this *really great* resource : http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Comment: So this scenario holds true for every time we need to use an input variable in place of any of the query's components?  And could you please let me know what you mean by SQL injection?  Is this query prone to SQL injection?

Comment: Yes it is, this is just an example on how to use dynamic sql. If this is not just intended to use internally, you should not use this syntax. Please read more about sql injection at this address http://www.securiteam.com/securityreviews/5DP0N1P76E.html